# Are apps built with the Remote Display API required to fulfill the reconnection and continuous playback requirements?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

According to *Test Case 1.30* of the [Google Cast Test Cases](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TctpFEnhsaqaUmq-JLFSzcWTZQytYtKdR05UQ8E-nRg/edit?usp=sharing):

> **Step:** Turn sender WiFi off for 20 sec
>
> **Expected Result:**
>
> - Sender does NOT crash
> - Cast icon not filled
> - Receiver continues playback uninterrupted
>
> **Step:** Turn WiFi on and connect to same network
>
> **Expected Result:**
>
> - Cast reconnects, cast icon filled

The above is listed as a [P0 test case](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/testing), where "Your application must not launch with a P0 bug." However, apps using the `Remote Display` API can't play back media when the sender is disconnected, because the content is being cast locally over WiFi. Additionally, I've noticed that on Android, the official Google Cast app's *Cast Screen/Audio* feature doesn't attempt to reconnect after a WiFi disconnect.

Are apps built with the Remote Display API required to fulfill the reconnection and continuous playback requirements?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know [Remote Display API](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_remote_display_channel) only has a feature of keeping a remote display session active and to resume after app backgrounding. Documentation doesn't mention about reconnecting after a WiFi disconnect.

And reading further through additional documentations, [Media Playback Messages](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/messages) states that:

> Google Cast sender applications control the playback on the receiver device by sending messages in JSON format to the receiver application. Likewise, the receiver sends messages back to the sender, also in JSON. The messages may be commands from the sender that change the player state, responses to those commands from the receiver, or data structures that describe the media for the receiver application.

From what I understand, you might need to initiate the [creation of connection](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote#create-the-connection) again after a change in player state or after a WiFi disconnection.